# Let B ⊂ R. Let L be the set of all limit points of B. Prove that B ∪ L contains all its limit points.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let B ⊂ R. Let L be the set of all limit points of B. Prove that B ∪ L contains all its limit points.

I have a question about this one.

Here is my proof

Suppose x is a limit point of B ∪ L and x does not belong to B ∪ L

If x is a limit point of B ∪ L, then x is either limit point of B or limit point of L (or both)

By assuming that x does not belong to B ∪ L

x is not in B and x is not in L

Here is where I am stuck and not sure whether this is right approach

Can anyone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $w$ is a limit point of $B\cup L$, then for all open ball $\beta_r(w)$ there is a $x\in \beta_r(w)$ such that $x\in B$ or $x\in L$, If $x\in L$ then there is $t<r$ such that $\beta_t(x)\subset\beta_r(w)$, how $x\in L$ then there is a $y\in\beta_t(x)$ such that $y \in B$ because $x$ is a limit point of $B$, therefor $w$ is a limit point of $B$ then $w\in L$ then $w\in B\cup L$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative proof (not entirely by contradiction). Let $x$ be a limit point of the union of $B$ and $L$.

Either every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $B$ or every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $L$, because otherwise there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ with no points from $B$ and another neighbourhood $W$ with no points from $L$. If that were the case, $V\cap W$ would be a neighbourhood of $x$ with no points from the union, contradicting the definition of $x$. *This proves the second statement in your proof.*

Now,

- The first case from the last paragraph means that $x$ is a limit point of $B$, so it belongs to $L$.
- In the second case, $x$ is a limit point of $L$. I claim that it also is a limit point of $B$. Indeed, any neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ contains a point in $L$, call it $y$. Note that $U$ is also a neighbourhood of $y$, and since $y$ is a limit point of $B$, it must contain a point from $B$ too. This means that $x$ is also limit point of $B$.

To sum up, in both cases $x$ is a limit point of $B$, and therefore belongs to the union. The result follows.

Answer (score 1):

"If x is a limit point of B ∪ L, then x is either limit point of B or limit point of L (or both)"

I don't think you can state this without proving it.  A limit point, p, of B $\cup$ U is one in which every neighborhood has a point other than p that is in B $\cup$ U.  I can imagine, however, that one neighborhood has a point in B while another has a point in U but not every neighborhood consistently has a point in either one.

But if p is a limit point of B $\cup$ L then every neighborhood N has a point q $\in$ B $\cup$ L.  If q is in L then q is a limit point of B so every of its neighborhoods has a point r in B.  Choose a neighborhood of q that has a small enough to be a subset of N.  So r $\in$ N.  So every neighborhood of q has a point in B.  So if p is limit point of B $\cup$ L the p is a limit point of B and thus a member of L.  So B $\cup$ L cointains all its limit points.

Answer (score 0):

You should prove a bit more rigorously your claim that "$x$ being a limit point of $B\cup L$ means $x$ is either a limit point of $B$ or a limit point of $L$". Once you can state that for certain, the next step I'd take is to say that $x$ cannot be a limit point of $B$, as that would mean $x \in L \subset B\cup L$. This forces $x$ to be strictly a limit point of $L$. Can you proceed from here to a contradiction?

Comment: sorry I do not see any contradiction...

Comment: @Garsa Do you agree with my reasoning that $x$ cannot be a limit point of $B$?

Comment: Is that your assumption?

Comment: @Garsa No... that's my claim. As i say in my answer, "$x$  cannot be a limit point of $B$, as that would mean $x\in L\subset B\cup L$"

Comment: I see that if x can not be a limit point of B, then x must be in L. However, L is the set of all limit points of B, thus contradiction

Comment: @Garsa We don't know that $x$ is in $L$ yet, just that $x$ is a limit point of $L$. But if you can show $x \in L$ you will indeed have a contradiction.

Comment: Could you explain more about your claim? "that x cant not be an limit point?"

Comment: @Garsa no, my claim is that $x$ is not a limit point **of B**. At this point in the proof we have $x$ as a limit point of $L$ such that $x \notin L$

Comment: Organizing my thoughts, so you claim that x is not a limit point of B. However, if x is limit point of Union, then x is either limit point of B or L. Then it follows x is a limit point of L. Then, it leads to a contradiction since L is the set of all limit points of B?

Comment: @Garsa Nope. Step 1: You need to prove that "if $x$ is a limit point of union, then $x$ is a limit point of $B$ or $x$ is a limit point of $L$."

That is not a trivial claim. When you have shown that, then: Step 2: Use what you proved in step 1. We now know $x$ is a limit point of $L$ or $B$. The definition of $L$ is that *it contains all of* $B$'s limit points. So if $x$ were a limit point of $B$, then $x$ would be contained in $L$, and hence $x$ would be contained in the union. This contradicts your assumption that $x$ is not in the union. So $x$ cannot be a limit point of $B$. Continue...